# How to intercept minimize message on WM 6.5

Tags: winapi, windows-mobile-6.5

I was trying to intercept the WM_SIZE message sent by the "X" button on windows mobile 6.5. I know that this message along with the minimize value in wParam can be used to do whatever we want.

However, the problem is, even if I implement my own behaviour for this event, the program gets minimized anyway. I tried putting a breakpoint and stopping execution at the WM_SIZE line, but by then the main app window is minimized.

I there a way to prevent it from minimizing on its own when we click the "X" button?

Answer (score 0):

Can you intercept it under [WM_SYSCOMMAND](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?   Look for SC_MINIMIZE and eat the message to keep it from minimizing.    We do this to keep applications in a Kiosk configuration.

WM_SIZE is too late, its sent AFTER the window has already been resized/maximized/minimized.